# Why is this coefficient interpretation incorrect in Regression?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

[image]

Question: 'Give an interpretation of the estimated coefficient of tempC'

My answer: holding fixed the type of event, an increase in temperature by 1 degree C means the winning race time will increase by 0.232 minutes.

Apparently the correct answer: **for the man's race**, an increase in temperature by 1 degree C means the winning race time will increase by 0.232 minutes.

Why is it for the man's race? My understanding was that we hold the other variables (excluding tempC) fixed, which *doesn't* mean using a value of 0 for the dummy variable, which is what would be needed to get the correct interpretation in my mind. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is 
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1wrace_i + \beta_2tempC_i + \beta_3tempC_i\times wrace_i + \epsilon_i,
$$
thus for womens' race you have 
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + (\beta_2 + \beta_3)tempC_i + \epsilon_i,
$$
and for men
$$
y_i = \beta_0 +  \beta_2tempC_i  + \epsilon_i.
$$
Namely, for women 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial tempC}\mathbb{E}[y|tempC, wrace=1]=\beta_2+\beta_3,
$$
while for men
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial tempC}\mathbb{E}[y|tempC, wrace=0]=\beta_2.
$$